# Loop and if Statement in php

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have the following code.

```
<?php if ( $showdata['venue'] == "Brean Sands" ) {echo "<div class=\"gigpress-related-park\">"; echo $showdata['date_long']; echo $showdata['venue']; echo "</div>"; } ?>
<?php if ( $showdata['venue'] == "Camber Sands" ) {echo "<div class=\"gigpress-related-park\">"; echo $showdata['date_long']; echo $showdata['venue']; echo "</div>"; } ?>
<?php if ( $showdata['venue'] == "Pakefield" ) {echo "<div class=\"gigpress-related-park\">"; echo $showdata['date_long']; echo $showdata['venue']; echo "</div>"; } ?>
<?php if ( $showdata['venue'] == "Prestatyn Sands" ) {echo "<div class=\"gigpress-related-park\">"; echo $showdata['date_long']; echo $showdata['venue']; echo "</div>"; } ?>
<?php if ( $showdata['venue'] == "Southport" ) {echo "<div class=\"gigpress-related-park\">"; echo $showdata['date_long']; echo $showdata['venue']; echo "</div>"; } ?>
```

This pulls the information from my db just fine, but I need it to loop, or repeat so that multiple dates appear for each venue. There are multiple dates for each venue in the db, but as the code is, it only returns the value for the first date. I need the others to appear as well.

How do I get this code to loop while looking at only one venue and pull all dates, then end?

Comment: how do you fetch the value from db? show us the code.

Comment: The Values are fetched here  http://pastebin.com/bfy1Cmug

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = mysql_query("the query");
while($showdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  put your code here
}
```

So you run the query to get all database records you want, then you loop through assigning the row to $showdata. This will then process everything inside the loop for every row it returns from the database query

Comment: Just use PDO or mysqli_* instead of mysql_*

Comment: I understand all of this, except the query. What do you mean? http://pastebin.com/bfy1Cmug I believe that is my query, it then include_once related, which contains the above code.

Comment: @PLB: thats an alternative, but not a direct solution. A loop would still be required whether you use PDO or mysqli, they are just alternative ways of interfacing with the data store.

Comment: @Lee I've suggested using pdo or mysqli_* only for security purposes.

Comment: @PLB: each to their own i guess. I have my own way and you have yours. However a little bit of knowledge can hurt sometimes. If mysqli is used incorrectly it can be insanely less secure and compromise a system far worse. i.e. the single biggest issue with mysqli (which is also its strength if you do things properly) is that it allows multiple sql statements. But as i say, we all have our own approach to a problem

Comment: @Lee I don't understand why you argue. First of all [`mysql` is deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Secondly, you can't do anything with sql injections using `mysql`.

Comment: Im not arguing, i give up. Your second proves your reading this stuff straight from a cookbook. goodbye

Answer (score 0):

assuming you use `mysql_` function to fetch values from db. here is what you should do.

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT QUERY');
while($showdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<div class=\"gigpress-related-park\">" . $showdata['venue'] . $showdata['venue'] . "</div>";
}
```

however it would be better of using PDO or MySQLi instead of using `mysql_`.

Comment: I believe my values are fetched by the following http://pastebin.com/bfy1Cmug  which then loads the above script through "related"